# Oracle select sum by time window

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Lets assume that we have the ORACLE table of the following format and data:

```
TIMESTAMP                 MESSAGENO              ORGMESSAGE                           
------------------------- ---------------------- -------------------------------------
27.04.13                  1                      START PERIOD  
27.04.13                  3                      10
27.04.13                  4                      5
28.04.13                  5                      6
28.04.13                  3                      20
29.04.13                  4                      25
29.04.13                  5                      26
30.04.13                  2                      END PERIOD
30.04.13                  1                      START PERIOD  
01.05.13                  3                      10
02.05.13                  4                      15
02.05.13                  5                      16
03.05.13                  3                      30
03.05.13                  4                      35
04.05.13                  5                      36
05.05.13                  2                      END PERIOD
```

I want to select sum of all the ORGMESSAGE for all the period (window between START PERIOD and END PERIOD) grouped by MESSAGENO.

Exapmle output would be:

```
PERIOD START  PERIOD END   MESSAGENO SUM 
------------ ------------- --------  ----
27.04.13     30.04.13        3        25
27.04.13     30.04.13        4        30
27.04.13     30.04.13        5        32
30.04.13     05.05.13        3        45
30.04.13     05.05.13        4        50
30.04.13     05.05.13        5        52
```

I am guessing that use of ORACLE Analityc function woulde be suitable but really dont know how and where to start.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Pleasy clarify. Obviously you *don't* group by messageno, as there are duplicate messageno in your result list.

Comment: I think I know what you want to do, but something is missing in your input data. Since there is no reliable ordering column, how can you tell which row dated 30.04.13 is "first" one?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the period starts and ends match, then a simple way to find the matching messages is to count the preceding number of starts.  This is a cumulative sum and it is easy in Oracle.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select min(timestamp) as periodstart, max(timestamp) as periodend, messageno, count(*)
from (select om.*,
             sum(case when messageno = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by timestamp) as grp
      from orgmessages om
     ) om
where messageno not in (1, 2)
group by grp, messageno;
```

Note that this method (as with the others) really wants the timestamp to be unique on each record.  In the data presented, these solutions will work.  But if you have multiple starts and ends on the same day, none of them will work assuming that `timestamp` only has the date.

Comment: Shouldn't messageno be in the group by?

Answer (score 0):

please, try this one, replace `rrr` with your table name

```
select periodstart, periodend, messageno, sum(to_number(orgmessage)) s
from (select TIMESTAMP periodstart,
             (select min (TIMESTAMP) from rrr r2 where orgmessage = 'END PERIOD' and r2.TIMESTAMP > r.TIMESTAMP) periodend
      from rrr r
      where orgmessage = 'START PERIOD'
) borders, rrr r
where r.TIMESTAMP between borders.periodstart and borders.periodend 
      and r.orgmessage not in ('END PERIOD', 'START PERIOD')
group by periodstart, periodend, messageno
order by periodstart, periodend, messageno
```

Answer (score 0):

First find all period ends per period start. Then join with your table to group and sum.

```
select 
  dates.start_date, 
  dates.end_date, 
  messageno, 
  sum(to_number(orgmessage)) as period_sum
from mytable
join
(
  select start_dates.timestmp as start_date, min(end_dates.timestmp) as end_date
  from (select * from mytable where orgmessage = 'START PERIOD') start_dates
  join (select * from mytable where orgmessage = 'END PERIOD') end_dates
    on start_dates.timestmp < end_dates.timestmp
  group by start_dates.timestmp
) dates on mytable.timestmp between dates.start_date and dates.end_date
where mytable.orgmessage not like '%PERIOD%'
group by dates.start_date, dates.end_date, messageno
order by dates.start_date, dates.end_date, messageno;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/365de/15.